# Android Intent Filter: Can't open audio file from preview?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I want my android app to be able to open MP3 files and a few other formats from a VIEW intent. I almost have this working but there are some cases where it won't show up in the "Open with..." menu.

For example, if I select an mp3 file in Files and choose "Open with" I see a list of apps that includes mine ("N-Space" in the screenshot).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq0ZV.png)

But when I tap the mp3 file it opens a preview. If I choose "Open with" from this preview screen, I get a *different* set of apps, which doesn't include mine.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMzXs.png)

Why would a different set of apps appear for the same file? Is it using a different MIME type or a different action type? How can I get my app to show up in that list?

Here's the relevant part of my manifest:

```
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />

        <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/mp3" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg3" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/x-mpeg-3" />
        <!-- ... and more for other file types -->
      </intent-filter>
```

I can't use `audio/*` because my app only supports certain audio formats.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the second "Open with..." menu shows a maximum of 3 apps. I uninstalled some of them and my app appeared. Might be a bug?